# Discord.js mysql query error not valid input

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord, discord.js

I wanted to make a MySQL query with my Discord.js bot, however, I always get an error.

My Code:

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("?userinfo")) {
        database.query("SELECT members FROM usertable WHERE username=?", [message.content], function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            //console.log(results[0]);

            var resultArray = Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results[0])));
            console.log(resultArray);
            steamid = resultArray;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you take over the complete message content and therefore the error occurs
create a variable and give it the message content

```
var messageContent = message.content.slice(10);
```

(slice takes the complete string and truncates it to the length specified)

And then replace the message.content in the sql query with "messageContent".

example:

```
    client.on('message', async message => {
        if (message.content.startsWith('?userinfo')) {
            var messageContent = message.content.slice(10);
            database.query('SELECT members FROM usertable WHERE username=?', [messageContent], function (err,results) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                //console.log(results[0]);
    
                var resultArray = Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results[0])));
                console.log(resultArray);
                steamid = resultArray;
            })
    
      }
    }
```